# Gradient of quadratic form with positive definite matrix in terms of Jacobian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, positive-definite, jacobian

I have recently encountered the following in a paper: Given $(\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{y(x)})^TU(\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{y(x)})$ where $U$ is a positive definite matrix independent of $x$ and $\boldsymbol{z}$ is also independent, the gradient with respect to $\boldsymbol{x}$ is:

$2\boldsymbol{\Delta}^TU[\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{y(x)}]$

where $\boldsymbol{\Delta}$ is the Jacobian of $\boldsymbol{y}$.

How does one show this?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3128040/357854) answers your question.